# rails rspec expected is not json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

My spec doesn't seem to be behaving properly, or rather my code isn't.

Here's my test:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  before(:each) do
    @os = FactoryGirl.create :deployer_os
    get :os
  end

  it 'returns all operating systems' do
    os_response = json_response
    expect(os_response).to eql @os
  end

  it { should respond_with 200 }
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :deployer_os, :class => 'DeployerOs' do
    platform 'darwin'
    version '10.10'
    description 'Yosemite'
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(os_response).to eql @os

   expected: #<DeployerOs id: 120, platform: "darwin", version: "10.10", description: "Yosemite", created_at: "2015-10-15 07:03:44", updated_at: "2015-10-15 07:03:44">
        got: {:deployer=>[{:id=>120, :platform=>"darwin", :version=>"10.10", :description=>"Yosemite", :created_at=>"2015-10-15T07:03:44.642Z", :updated_at=>"2015-10-15T07:03:44.642Z"}]}

   (compared using eql?)

   Diff:
   ...
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this? I'm getting the result I want but I don't think I'm writing my test correctly.

### Update

Modifying my test like this works but I'm wondering if this is the best way to accomplish this?

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  before(:each) do
    @os = JSON.parse((FactoryGirl.create :deployer_os).to_json, symbolize_names: true)
    get :os
  end

  it 'returns all operating systems' do
    os_response = json_response
    expect(os_response).to eql @os
  end

  it { should respond_with 200 }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have json in response but compare with object, why?
Try next:

```
@os.to_json
```

But @os - it's singe object and in the response you have an array.
For good decision you must consider what you want go get from request.

Comment: Right, so I need to change my object to json. I think this will work: `@os = JSON.parse((FactoryGirl.create :deployer_os).to_json, symbolize_names: true)` Is there a better way to write/accomplish this?

Comment: Ended up doing what I outlined in my comment above. This answer led me to the solution.